# Submitting every steps

Tags: jquery, jquery-steps

I am using jquery steps for a form wizard. Then I want the steps to have different forms, everytime step changes, with previous or next buttons, I d like to submit the form via ajax.

When i tried with multiple forms, it didnt work, cause `var form = $("#example-advanced-form").show();` 
so i guess i cant use multiple forms?

Does that mean, I should submit the whole form everytime I change a step? Well i cant really do that, because in different steps there are validation rules on server side.

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery steps might not be the right solution for you. If you have quite different forms to present based on the data provided, I think you have two options:

1) Do it in JavaScript. I'd probably caution against this because it would be exposing a lot of your business logic (if x then display y) in your javascript.

2) Use partial views (in MVC) based on the model that's being sent in. If I had something really complicated to work with, personally I'd rather have that in MVC land than in JavaScript, but that's a personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Add `$('#wizard-p-'+currentIndex).submit()` in `onStepChanging` and create submit function like this

`$('#wizard-p-0').submit(function(e) {
            var $form = $(this);
            var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
            var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
            $.ajax({
                    url : formURL,
                    type : "POST",
                    data : postData,
                    async : true,
                    success : function(data) {
                        //success code
                    },
                    error : function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
                        //error code
                    }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }`

This function is for submitting step-1. Make same functions for every relevant steps.